# Тег <text> в SVG при изменении ширины элемента в Safari запаздывает

Tags: html, css, svg

Отрисованные элементы, например `<path>`, `<line>`, `<rect>` и другие, при смене ширины браузера меняется моментально, но тег `<text>` обновляется с задержкой (рывками).
При этом `text-rendering` не срабатывает.

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 8)" class="st0 st1 st2">Hello, world! This is a simple SVG text for testing.</text>
```

Код: https://codepen.io/jamesscreen/pen/oNovBYO

Answer (score 5):

> Отрисованные элементы, например , ,  и другие, при
> смене ширины браузера меняется моментально, но тег  обновляется
> с задержкой (рывками).

Возможно и другое решение: заменить ресурсоёмкие матричные вычисления `transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 8)"` на позиционирование текста с помощью координат `x` `y`

```
<text x="1" y="8" class="st0 st1 st2">Hello, world! This is a simple SVG text for testing.</text>
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 129.7 9.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 129.7 9.5;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@500');
    .st0{fill:#182540;}
  .st1{font-family:'Playfair Display';font-weight: 500;}
    .st2{font-size:5.496px;}
    .st3{fill:none;stroke:#324093;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<text x="1" y="8" class="st0 st1 st2">Hello, world! This is a simple SVG text for testing.</text>
<rect class="st3" width="129.7" height="9.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="2" y1="0.5" x2="2" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="4" y1="0.5" x2="4" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="6" y1="0.5" x2="6" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="8" y1="0.5" x2="8" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="12" y1="0.5" x2="12" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="14" y1="0.5" x2="14" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="16" y1="0.5" x2="16" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="18" y1="0.5" x2="18" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="22" y1="0.5" x2="22" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="24" y1="0.5" x2="24" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="26" y1="0.5" x2="26" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="28" y1="0.5" x2="28" y2="1.5"/>
<line class="st3" x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="32" y1="0.4" x2="32" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="34" y1="0.4" x2="34" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="36" y1="0.4" x2="36" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="38" y1="0.4" x2="38" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="40" y1="-0.1" x2="40" y2="1.9"/>
<line class="st3" x1="42" y1="0.4" x2="42" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="44" y1="0.4" x2="44" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="46" y1="0.4" x2="46" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="48" y1="0.4" x2="48" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="50" y1="0.4" x2="50" y2="3.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="52" y1="0.4" x2="52" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="54" y1="0.4" x2="54" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="56" y1="0.4" x2="56" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="58" y1="0.4" x2="58" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="60" y1="-0.1" x2="60" y2="1.9"/>
<line class="st3" x1="62" y1="0.4" x2="62" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="64" y1="0.4" x2="64" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="66" y1="0.4" x2="66" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="68" y1="0.4" x2="68" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="70" y1="-0.1" x2="70" y2="1.9"/>
<line class="st3" x1="72" y1="0.4" x2="72" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="74" y1="0.4" x2="74" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="76" y1="0.4" x2="76" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="78" y1="0.4" x2="78" y2="1.4"/>
<line class="st3" x1="80" y1="-0.1" x2="80" y2="1.9"/>
<line class="st3" x1="82" y1="0.2" x2="82" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="84" y1="0.2" x2="84" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="86" y1="0.2" x2="86" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="88" y1="0.2" x2="88" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="90" y1="-0.2" x2="90" y2="1.8"/>
<line class="st3" x1="92" y1="0.2" x2="92" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="94" y1="0.2" x2="94" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="96" y1="0.2" x2="96" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="98" y1="0.2" x2="98" y2="1.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="100" y1="0.2" x2="100" y2="3.2"/>
<line class="st3" x1="102" y1="0.1" x2="102" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="104" y1="0.1" x2="104" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="106" y1="0.1" x2="106" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="108" y1="0.1" x2="108" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="110" y1="-0.4" x2="110" y2="1.6"/>
<line class="st3" x1="112" y1="0.1" x2="112" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="114" y1="0.1" x2="114" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="116" y1="0.1" x2="116" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="118" y1="0.1" x2="118" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="120" y1="-0.4" x2="120" y2="1.6"/>
<line class="st3" x1="122" y1="0.1" x2="122" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="124" y1="0.1" x2="124" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="126" y1="0.1" x2="126" y2="1.1"/>
<line class="st3" x1="128" y1="0.1" x2="128" y2="1.1"/>
</svg>
```

Линейку зубцов можно заменить на svg pattern, код значительно уменьшится, не нужно будет прорисовывать каждую линию много раз.
В паттерне определяем 4 коротких, вертикальных  линии и одну длинную.  Далее этот паттерн автоматически, многократно повторяется на всей длине.

[Подробнее о pattern](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875)

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   viewBox="0 0 129.7 9.5">
<style type="text/css">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@500');
    .st0{fill:#182540;}
  .st1{font-family:'Playfair Display';font-weight: 500;}
    .st2{font-size:5.496px;}
    .st3{fill:none;stroke:#324093;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
 <text x="1" y="8" class="st0 st1 st2">Hello, world! This is a simple SVG text for testing.</text> 
 
<defs>
<pattern id="patt"
             x="1" y="0" width="10" height="9.5"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <g stroke="#324093" stroke-width="1">         
 <line  x1="1" y1="0.5" x2="1" y2="1.5"/>
 <line  x1="3" y1="0.5" x2="3" y2="1.5"/> 
 <line  x1="5" y1="0.5" x2="5" y2="1.5"/> 
 <line  x1="7" y1="0.5" x2="7" y2="1.5"/> 
 <line  x1="9" y1="0.5" x2="9" y2="2.5" stroke="1"/> 
    </g> 
</pattern>
</defs> 
<rect  fill="url(#patt)" width="130" height="9.5" stroke="#324093"/>     

</svg>
```

Это лишнее в шапке SVG:
`style="enable-background:new 0 0 129.7 9.5;" xml:space="preserve"`
Сейчас это не применяется, осталось как атавизм в векторных редакторах.

Comment: @jamesscreen Если ответ вам был полезен, то можно принять его

Answer (score 2):

Недосмотрел. Решение оказалось простым. Нужно было прописать `text-rendering` со значением `geometricPrecision` либо в svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 129.7 9.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 129.7 9.5;" xml:space="preserve" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">
```

либо в CSS стили

```
.st1{font-family:'Playfair Display';font-weight: 500;text-rendering:geometricPrecision}
```